# Removing dictionaries from a list on the basis of duplicate value of key

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to Python. Suppose i have the following list of dictionaries:

```
mydictList= [{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},{'a':2,'b':2,'c':4},{'a':2,'b':3,'c':4}]
```

From the above list, i want to remove dictionaries with same value of key b. So the resultant list should be:

```
mydictList = [{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},{'a':2,'b':3,'c':4}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, sort the list by b-values (Python's sorting algorithm is stable, so dictionaries with identical `b` values will retain their relative order).

```
from operator import itemgetter
tmp1 = sorted(mydictList, key=itemgetter('b'))
```

Next, use `itertools.groupby` to create subiterators that iterate over dictionaries with the same `b` value.

```
import itertools
tmp2 = itertools.groupby(tmp1, key=itemgetter('b))
```

Finally, create a new list that contains only the first element of each subiterator:

```
# Each x is a tuple (some-b-value, iterator-over-dicts-with-b-equal-some-b-value)
newdictList = [ next(x[1]) for x in tmp2 ]
```

Putting it all together:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

by_b = itemgetter('b')
newdictList = [ next(x[1]) for x in groupby(sorted(mydictList, key=by_b), key=by_b) ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new dictionary based on the value of `b`, iterating the `mydictList` backwards (since you want to retain the first value of `b`), and get only the values in the dictionary, like this

```
>>> {item['b'] : item for item in reversed(mydictList)}.values()
[{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'c': 4, 'b': 3}]
```

If you are using Python 3.x, you might want to use `list` function over the dictionary values, like this

```
>>> list({item['b'] : item for item in reversed(mydictList)}.values())
```

**Note:** This solution may not maintain the order of the dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

A very straight forward approach can go something like this:

```
mydictList= [{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},{'a':2,'b':2,'c':4},{'a':2,'b':3,'c':4}]

b_set = set()
new_list = []

for d in mydictList:
    if d['b'] not in b_set:
        new_list.append(d)
        b_set.add(d['b'])
```

Result:

```
>>> new_list
[{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'c': 4, 'b': 3}]
```