# Remove duplicate dictionary from a list on the basis of key value by priority

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates

Suppose I have the following type of list of dictionaries:

```
iterlist = [
    {"Name": "Mike", "Type": "Admin"},
    {"Name": "Mike", "Type": "Writer"},
    {"Name": "Mike", "Type": "Reader"},
    {"Name": "Zeke", "Type": "Writer"},
    {"Name": "Zeke", "Type": "Reader"}
]
```

I want to remove duplicates of "Name" on the basis of "Type" by the following priority (Admin > Writer > Reader), so the end result should be:

```
iterlist = [
    {"Name": "Mike", "Type": "Admin"},
    {"Name": "Zeke", "Type": "Writer"}
]
```

I found a similar question but it removes duplicates for one explicit type of key-value: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028593/removing-dictionaries-from-a-list-on-the-basis-of-duplicate-value-of-key)

Can someone please guide me on how to move forward with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a modified form of the solution suggested by @azro, their solution and the other solution does not take into account the priority you mentioned, you can get over that using the following code. Have a priority dict.

```
iterlist = [
    {"Name": "Mike", "Type": "Writer"},
    {"Name": "Mike", "Type": "Reader"},
    {"Name": "Mike", "Type": "Admin"},
    {"Name": "Zeke", "Type": "Reader"},
    {"Name": "Zeke", "Type": "Writer"}
]

# this is used to get the priority
priorites = {i:idx for idx, i in enumerate(['Admin', 'Writer', 'Reader'])}

sort_key = lambda x:(x['Name'], priorites[x['Type']])
groupby_key = lambda x:x['Name']

result = [next(i[1]) for i in groupby(sorted(iterlist, key=sort_key), key=groupby_key)]
print(result)
```

Output

```
[{'Name': 'Mike', 'Type': 'Admin'}, {'Name': 'Zeke', 'Type': 'Writer'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `pandas` in the following way:

1. transform the list of dictionary to data frame:

   ```
   import pandas as pd

   df = pd.DataFrame(iterlist)
   ```
2. create a mapping dict:

   ```
   m = {'Admin': 3, 'Writer': 2, 'Reader': 1}
   ```
3. create a priority column using [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

   ```
   df['pri'] = df['Type'].replace(m)
   ```
4. [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by `pri` and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by `Name` and get the first element only:

   ```
   df = df.sort_values('pri', ascending=False).groupby('Name').first().reset_index()
   ```
5. [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the `pri` column and return to dictionary using [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

   ```
   df.drop('pri', axis='columns').to_dict(orient='records')
   ```

This will give you the following:

```
[{'Name': 'Mike', 'Type': 'Admin'}, {'Name': 'Zeke', 'Type': 'Writer'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution you can try out,

```
unique = {}

for v in iterlist:
    # check if key exists, if not update to `unique` dict
    if not unique.get(v['Name']):
        unique[v['Name']] = v
        
print(unique.values())
```

---

```
dict_values([{'Name': 'Mike', 'Type': 'Admin'}, {'Name': 'Zeke', 'Type': 'Writer'}])
```